# WEB scrapping con R

Tags: r

Me gustaría obtener la localización de cajeros en España a través del **VISA ATM locator**(https://www.visa.com/atmlocator/mobile/index.jsp#(page:results,params:(query:Spain))). Los resultados para España se muestran en una tabla, pero no se como acceder a esos elementos. Esto he intentado:

```
link <- "https://www.visa.com/atmlocator/mobile/index.jsp#(page:results,params:(query:Spain))"
visa_webpage <- read_html(link)
visa_webpage %>%
html_nodes("visaATMResultListItem") %>% 
html_text()
>>character(0)
```

¿Ustedes saben como puedo obtener los resultados?

Comment: Hello, we are at Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered ;)

Comment: Por favor Diana, traduce el texto al español puesto que estamos en StackOverflow en español.

Comment: Viendo la página, seguro que con `rvest` NO, este paquete va bien para páginas estáticas, el problema es que el enlace que pasaste requiere interactividad por parte del usuario, ya el link lo primero que hace es preguntarte de que "Spain" estamos hablando, y la tabla que finalmente te ofrece tiene botones de navegación a los cuales deberías ir haciendo click para poder capturar cada página. Te sugiero que investigues por el lado de: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html